# Pandas: Series вывод значений по типу данных

Tags: python, pandas

Имеется объект `Series` с различными типами данных: `int`, `str`, `float`. Мне необходимо выбрать значения только с типом данных `int` и произвести с ними вычисления.

Как выбрать значения определенного типа данных?

Comment: можете привести воспроизводимый пример данных? И что делать, например, с числами, которые представлены в виде строк - надо ли их суммировать?

Answer (score 2):

Пример:

```
In [31]: s = pd.Series([1, 1.11, "XXX", 3, 3.33])

In [32]: s
Out[32]:
0       1
1    1.11
2     XXX
3       3
4    3.33
dtype: object

In [33]: s.loc[s.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, int))].sum()
Out[33]: 4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = pd.Series([1, 1.11, "XXX", 3, 3.33])
```

ну вот так еще можно (данные позаимствовал у MaxU):

```
s[s.astype('str').str.isdecimal()]
```

получим:

```
0    1
3    3
dtype: object
```

Либо сразу аггрегатор:

```
s[s.astype('str').str.isdecimal()].sum()
```

> 4